# ASP.NET CORE Identity DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions Password reset token is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

For my application i implemented ASP.NET Core Identity. I generate a password reset token with GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(). It works fine if i reset the password within 1 Day. After 1 Day it won't work anymore. i Get a 'invalid token' message. I already setted the TokenLifeSpan in the DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions to Timespan.FromDays(3), but that still doesnt seem to work.

But if i change my password within, it does work. Can someone help me because i'm really stuck with this issue. thankyou.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DUMMY_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DUMMY_DBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please put a snippet of your `startup.cs` code here. You can [edit] your question above.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal ??

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have done. Taking a long-shot, maybe try writing your last line like `services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => { o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3); });` Note I have just added curly braces.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few things: Add a name to the custom token, set the token you want to use for the password reset and add it on identity.

Your code should look like this:

```
      services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            
            //Configure must be before you register the service 
            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o => { 
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
                o.Name = "3DaysToken";
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<DUMMY_DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
                options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = "3DaysToken"; //Set password token provider
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DUMMY_DBContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddTokenProvider<
                    DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>(
                    "3DaysToken"); //Added extended token provider
            }
```